# MYSQL Using Limit In Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this kind of query that need to limit by 3 in each 'region' group but it doesnt run as I expected. The 'row_number' seems not arranged accordingly.
There must be some syntax I missed out or I didnt know. If anyone can help I dump the sql [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZzLs_ZW5aiLmPlsEDg58g5k5_1w0psto). MYSQL version 5.0

My query :

```
set @type = '';
set @num = 0;

SELECT locinvaisle.Area as ar,locinvaisle.Region as rg,custlist.CustomerName as cn,custlist.Custtype ct,
       SUM(data2.quantity/1000) as mtcur,
       @num := if(@type = locinvaisle.Region, @num + 1, 1) as dummy_1,
  @type := locinvaisle.Region as dummy_2,
  @num as row_number

FROM data2

  INNER JOIN custlist ON data2.customeracc = custlist.Customeraccount
  INNER JOIN locinvaisle ON data2.location = locinvaisle.Location

WHERE
   date1 >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-01-01') AND date1 <= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-%m-31')
  AND
   data2.unit = 'KG'
  AND
   data2.customeracc not in (select Customeraccount from custlist WHERE Custcat = 'bcsb')
  AND
   locinvaisle.Area = 'peninsular'
  AND
   custlist.Custtype = 'others'

GROUP BY locinvaisle.Region,custlist.CustomerName
HAVING row_number < 3
ORDER BY locinvaisle.Region,mtcur desc
```

Results :

[image: results]

Desired Results(From dummy database) :

[image: dummy]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: MySQL makes no guarantees about the order in which a select statement gets executed.  So, `row_number` could happen before or after `dummy_1`.  My advice would be to just run the query with variables without aggregating first, to materialize out the row numbers.  Then, subquery that and aggregate.  At least, I have had success using this approach in the past.

Comment: If you add a demo for your query, maybe someone can have a look.

Comment: Thank for response.I'd try run the query with variables without aggregating first, the row_number seems arranged accordingly but the grouping for region isnt. The demo is quite big,so I put it on the hyperlink above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the limiting as a full subquery ("derived table") before the group by is applied. Something along these lines:

```
SELECT 
       ar, rg, cn, ct, sum(quantity)
FROM (
    SELECT
          @row_num :=IF(@prev_value = locinvaisle.Region, @row_num + 1, 1)AS RowNumber
        , locinvaisle.Area as ar
        , locinvaisle.Region as rg
        , custlist.CustomerName as cn
        , custlist.Custtype ct
        , data2.quantity
        , @prev_value := locinvaisle.Region as dummy_2,
    FROM data2
      INNER JOIN custlist ON data2.customeracc = custlist.Customeraccount
      INNER JOIN locinvaisle ON data2.location = locinvaisle.Location
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='') vars
    WHERE date1 >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-01-01') AND date1 <= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-%m-31')
      AND data2.unit = 'KG'
      AND data2.customeracc not in (select Customeraccount from custlist WHERE Custcat = 'bcsb')
      AND  locinvaisle.Area = 'peninsular'
      AND custlist.Custtype = 'others'
    ORDER BY locinvaisle.Region,mtcur desc
    ) d
WHERE rowNumber <= 3
GROUP BY ar, rg, cn, ct
ORDER BY ar, rg, cn, ct
```

NOTE: You need to apply an `ORDER BY` within the subquery to facilitate the rownumber calculation, but despite this there is no guarantee that the final output will be in the desired order unless you apply a final order by clause.

Also please note that in future versions of MySQL (V8 and above) there should be a `row_number()` function and `over()` clause that can be used instead of the variables seen above.

Comment: Maybe...but I see other problems with the query, and without providing a working demo or code, your answer really belongs as a comment.

Comment: I'd try your query @Used_By_Already, but the row_number didnt arranged accordingly. What do you mean by apply a final order by clause?

Comment: To calculate rownumber you need a specific order. After that you might need a second (final) order. That's all. The more important point is you need to calculate rownumber first, then select the rows, then group by.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you need to be careful when using variables.  Two things are important:

- Variables should be assigned and referenced in the same expression.
- You need to be careful about the ordering of the result set.

So, try something like this:

```
SELECT x.*,
       (@rn := IF(@r = la.Region, @num + 1,
                  IF(@r := la.Region, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rn
FROM (SELECT la.Area as ar, la.Region as rg, c.CustomerName as cn, c.Custtype ct,
             SUM(data2.quantity/1000) as mtcur
      FROM data2 d INNER JOIN
           custlist c
           ON d.customeracc = c.Customeraccount  INNER JOIN
           locinvaisle la
           ON d.location = la.Location
      WHERE date1 >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-01-01') AND
            date1 <= DATE_FORMAT('2018-06-11', '%Y-%m-31') AND
            d.unit = 'KG' AND
            d.customeracc not in (select Customeraccount from custlist cl WHERE cl Custcat = 'bcsb') AND
            la.Area = 'peninsular' AND
            c.Custtype = 'others'
      GROUP BY la.Region, c.CustomerName
     ) x CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @r := 0, @rn := 0) params
HAVING rn <= 3;
```